regex for capturing first or second instance of element
I have a series of strings that look like this:
08:00 0160:00 0000:00 0160:00
0000:00 0000:00
09:00 08:00 0120:00 0120:00

etc.
I need a regex to capture the first and another one to caputre the second string in the format xxxx:xx.
Already tried:
\s\b\d{4}:\d{2}\s
(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}
\b\d{4}:\d{2}
(?<=\s)\d{4}:\d{2}(?=\s)
^\d\s\b\d{4}:\d{2}\s

Unfortunately due to different reasons they are not working.
Also tried to follow some istructions here: Capture first or second instance of match but I have some issues in applying them to my case.
I'll use the regex in a front end env that accepts the regex only, so no options for retreiving instances with coding, I need the regex to do all the work.
The front end is an OCR tool which detects some text, so I have long strings of data and I need to isolate some fields that could vary.
I'm using this website to test my regex:
https://regex101.com/
All that I need is to match (not group) the output expected.
Thanks

you didn't tell where you are going to use such regex (if a text editor or a programming language).. the only hint was given in the third SO question linked (being javascript). By the way, despite there are ways to instruct a regex to match the second occurrence of such pattern.. can't you just use a generic pattern like \d{4}:\d{2} and then from the evaluator just fetch the first and second occurences alone? of course it's a suggestion given to better inspect the scenario because it's not clear... it's not taking for granted it's what you actually needed

You should explain what regex engine is used "under the hood", (?<!\S)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\S) will find the string you need, but how does that front end behave? We cannot help you without more details.

Beside what already has been mentioned by Diego and Wiktor, is something like that heading into the right direction ?.. /\b(\d{4}:\d{2})\b.*?\b(\d{4}:\d{2})\b/gm

I've added details, I don't know much about what is "under the hood", I usually use regex101 and if something is matching there, thenit'is always fine in my tool. So I need two regex, one for the first element, one for the second, none of yours is working, as they are capturing pretty much everything

as I said in my previous comment, it's still possible to instruct the regex to capture only the first and the second occurence in 2 separate expressions. And it would work on regex101 but yet it's addressing groups... the actual match will still be the first captured group and not the entire match itself, The trick is using non capturing groups... this is an example to match the second occurrence only (?:.*?\d{4}:\d{2}){1}.*?(\d{4}:\d{2}). But yet it still uses groups!

Honestly I don't understand what I need to add to be more clear, it's specified that "not groups". My tool doesn't support groups, it shows only the matches, so I need the match, not the group. Let's suppose my tool is regex101, I need the regex to be desplayed on regex101 as a match, without using groups. If this is not possible that's still fine, I just need to know.

@Federicofkt ... are we talking about matching every first (respectively second) occurrence of the pattern at each new line of the entire multiline string. Or are we talking about matching just the 1st/2nd occurrence within the entire multiline string? And does the regex engine support a negative/positive lookbehind?

Yes it supports negative/positive lookbehind. I'm looking to match at each new line, every linee represents an example of the text that I can find, so I need only one regex (two in total, for first and second element xxxx:xx) that generalizes all of the example provided, one by one, not multilinear

does your regex flavour support variable length lookbehind?

what goes wrong with your \b\d{4}:\d{2} example?

It matches every instance of xxxx:xx, I only need the first and the second, in two separate regex

If it matches every instance, then you have some global flag on. Can you turn it off? Can you tell us a bit more about what the environment is? Documentation?

First match: ^.*?\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d)
Second match: ^.*?(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d).*?\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d)
Explanation

\d{4}:\d{2}: This will match 0000:00 but it will also match larger blocks, like 00000:000.
(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d): The negative assertions will prevent larger blocks, but the pattern matches every occurrence of 0000:00, not just the first one, when the search is continued to return multiple matches (OP seems unable to switch off the g global flag).
^.*?(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d): The start-of-line anchor (^) and the lazy-match-anything subpattern (.*?) will consume everything from start until the first 0000:00, so the second occurrence of 0000:00 will not match when the search continues. However, the returned match will also contain all the initial stuff.
^.*?\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d): The escape sequence \K resets the start-of-match position, so the previously matched characters (initial stuff) will not be included in the final match, only the first 0000:00-like substring. This pattern answers the OP's first question.
^.*?(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d).*?\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d): Compared with the previous pattern, the initial lazy-match-anything subpattern (.*?) is appended by (?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d).*?, which matches the first 0000:00, so that we can capture the second one. This is a solution to the OP's second question.
^.*?((?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d).*?){123}\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d): This will match 0000:00-like strings 123 times before returning with the 124th occurrence. (Replace 123 with whatever number you wish.)

Note, that ^ anchors the start of each line if you have a multi-line subject string and the global flag m is set. If so, the above will find the 1st (or 2nd) occurrences in each line. If you only want the very first of all lines, either clear the global flag m, or replace ^ with the start-of-string anchor \A:
First match: \A.*?\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d)
Second match: \A.*?(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d).*?\K(?<!\d)\d{4}:\d{2}(?!\d)
